# T is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial for T has the form $ p = (x-c_1)...(x-c_n) $

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

> Theroem 6: Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field F
>   and let T be a linear operator on V. Then T is diagonalizable if and only if the
>   minimal polynomial for T has the form 
>   $$ p = (x-c_1)...(x-c_n) $$
>   where $c_1,...c_n$ are distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}$.
>
> Proof from Hoffman, Kunze:
>
> We have noted earlier that, if $T$ is diagonalizable, its minimal
>   polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors (see the discussion
>   prior to Example 4).
>
> To prove the converse, let $W$ be the
>   subspace spanned by all of the characteristic vectors of $T$, and
>   suppose $W \ne V$.
>
> By the lemma used in the proof of Theorem 5,
>   there is a vector $\alpha$ not in $W$ and a characteristic value $c_j$
>   of $T$ such that the vector $\beta= (T - c_jI)\alpha$ lies in W.
>
> Since $\beta$ is in $W$, $\beta = \beta_1+\dots\beta_k$ where
>   $T\beta_i = c_i\beta_i$, $1\le i\le k$, and therefore the vector
>   $h(T)\beta = h(c_1)\beta_1+\dots+h(c_k)\beta_k$ is in $W$, for every
>   polynomial $h$.
>
> Now $p = (x-c_j)q$, for some polynomial $q$.
>
> Also $q- q(c_j) = (x - c_j)h$.
>
> We have $q(T)\alpha - q(c_j)\alpha = h(T)(T - c_jI)\alpha = h(T)\beta$.
>
> But $h(T)\beta$
>   is in $W$ and, since $0 = p(T)\alpha = (T - c_jI)q(T)\alpha$, the
>   vector $q(T)\alpha$ is in $W$.
>
> Therefore, $q(c_j)\alpha$ is in
>   $W$.
>
> Since $\alpha$ is not in $W$, we have $q(c_j) = 0$.
>
> That contradicts the fact that $p$ has distinct roots.

Can you explain why it is given that $q(x) - q(c_j) = (x-c_j)h(x)$? I don't understand this part so I don't quite get the remaining proof of the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $c_j$ is a root of $q(x)-q(c_j)$. Hence $q(x)-q(c_j)=(x-c_j)h(x)$ for some polynomial $h$.